# Move Computer to another Domain w/o contact to the old domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions

i have to move computers to a new Domain, but no domain rights in the old domain, only local admin rights on the computers
The Computers run under Windows7 32 bit.

I tryed it with netdom and ps Add-Computer, but without domain rights it dont work.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to remove it from the old domain. Change the computer to workgroup first, then join the new domain.  When prompted for credentials, enter the local administrator credentials (.\Administrator).

Comment: When prompted for credentials for the old domain, just enter anything. When credentials cannot be verified, the machine will just drop the trust relationship with the domain without deactivating the computer account through the DC.

Comment: Joining the new domain requires entering domain admin credentials, not local, however the user doing the joining must be a local admin as well. Strictly speaking you can supply any domain account that has the right to join computers.